# Lock out iTunes Store

Tags: itunes, ipad

Can I lock out the iTunes store so no purchases can be made on my iPad?
I don't see that possibility in Settings.
I accidentally purchased music I did not want and tried to cancel it immediately but couldn't. I want to be able to buy apps but no music.

Comment: Settings > General > Restrictions. It's all there.

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > General > Restrictions. Turn iTunes Store off. As long as you leave the Installing Apps setting on, you should still be able to access the App Store.